# Why have pictures on Instagram got blurry since my iPad has been updated to iOS9?

Tags: ios, ipad, instagram

I recently updated to iOS9 on my iPad4, and ever since then the pictures on Instagram have been blurry (It looked fine previously). Is this an Instagram bug, old Hardware, or something else?

---

Let me know if this is the wrong site to ask on.

Comment: Do you have iCloud Photo Library activated? And if so, do you have "Optimise iPad Storage" enabled? If you do, what it does is just render small thumbnails of your full resolution photos on the camera photo albums. When you try to access them via the Instagram App most of the times those photos aren't stored on the device but on the iCloud. In order to access the full resolution photo, mark them as favourites and make sure they are Full Resolution on the Photos App and then try to access them on the Instagram App.

Comment: My pictures only get blurry once I post them, and everybody else's posts are to. I do not have iCloud Photo Library enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that the Instagram app was programmed for the older OS and needs an update. You could check their support forums, but it also might be something you just wait out for the next few app updates to post from the vendor.

It also could just be server side changes - if your iPad isn't served the complete resolution images, you won't have them. (i.e. the problem might not exist on your device at all).

Comment: I notified the support team about the issue, so hopefully they will fix it in the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I missed the update that was released with the new OS, after the update, everything works great!