# My Instagram photos on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, instagram

The pictures on my Instagram (not my account) are all blurry, and the videos won't work. Not all pictures and videos do it though, just some.

Comment: Did you update to iOS9 then it started happening?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Different!

I had this issue when I updated to iOS9 (though I think I could play videos, I don't remember). All it was is I missed the Instagram update. Here is the question I asked: [Why have pictures on Instagram got blurry since my iPad has been updated to iOS9?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208116/why-have-pictures-on-instagram-got-blurry-since-my-ipad-has-been-updated-to-ios9)